# How to disable the support section on Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How does one disable the support section on the Chrome Web Store?

[This extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai?hl=en-GB&authuser=0) managed to do it but I cannot find anywhere in the settings how to do that.

[image]

Comment: Maybe from the [CWS Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole)?

Comment: I had a look there but didn't find any option.